# Kartiv yii2 datepicker with model and custom id

Tags: yii2

I am using kartik datepicker extension http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker in Yii2.

Issue :

If I use this with custom id for input it does not show show model validations

```
   echo kartik\date\DatePicker::widget([
             'model' => $objPatientModel,
             'form'=>$objActiveForm,
             'attribute' => 'date_of_birth',
             'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter birth date ...', 'id' => 'patient_dob'], **// with id clientside validations for model does not work**
             'pluginOptions' => [
                 'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                 'endDate' => date('d-m-Y'),
             ]
         ]);
```

While below code works

```
 echo kartik\date\DatePicker::widget([
             'model' => $objPatientModel,
             'form'=>$objActiveForm,
             'attribute' => 'date_of_birth',
             'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter birth date ...'],**//id is not used here**
             'pluginOptions' => [
                 'format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy',
                 'endDate' => date('d-m-Y'),
             ]
         ]);
```

But I want to use custom id .Any suggestions ?

Comment: any specific reasons for using id ? for custom js you can play with class also

Comment: @KandarpPatel actually I have different forms add and edit on one single page .I am hiding and showing the forms according to the requirements .Now because I have to display date of birth field from one model for add and edit on same page .. date picker is not working on second field reason being id is same . So I want to have different ids for both fields . But seems that the id mentioned in option goes unnoticed for active form .. Any help of suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the selectors, example:

```
$form->field($model, 'comment', ['selectors' => ['input' => '#myCustomId']])
        ->textarea(['id' => 'myCustomId']);?>
```

See https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7627

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?=
        $form->field($model, 'sales_date')->widget(DateControl::classname(), [
            'name' => 'sales_date',
            'value' => date('d-m-Y h:i:s'),
            'type' => DateControl::FORMAT_DATETIME,
            'autoWidget' => true,
            'displayFormat' => 'php:d-m-Y h:i:s',
            'saveFormat' => 'php:Y-m-d h:i:s',
            'saveOptions' => [
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'form' => 'sales-form-red',
            ],
        ])
  ?>
```

by using the following option you can add extra form tag to input

```
'saveOptions' => [
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'form' => 'sales-form-red',
                'class' => 'sales_date',
            ]
```

In my case out was

```
<input type="hidden" id="sales-sales_date" name="Sales[sales_date]" form="sales-form-red">
```

check by using link
[Date Control Demo](https://demos.krajee.com/datecontrol-demo#configure)